# Pandas get group, how to get group by keywords out of a phrase?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So let's say I have the following:

| Item | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| Blue Banana | 3 |
| Red Banana | 4 |
| Green Banana | 1 |
| Blue Apple | 2 |
| Orange Apple | 6 |

I would like to grab all of the bananas and add them, no matter the color.
Or I would like to grab all Blue item, no matter the fruit type, and add them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension and `str.contains`:

```
words = ['banana', 'blue']

pd.Series({w: df.loc[df['Item'].str.contains(w, case=False), 'Quantity'].sum()
            for w in words})
```

output:

```
banana    8
blue      5
```